# I am new to android services and I have some questions

Tags: android, service, location, fusedlocationproviderapi, fusedlocationproviderclient

1. I want to develop a service that will work in background even the app gets killed. In my scenario I am getting location updates using fusedlocationproviderclient and sending it to database. The problem is that when I put app to background using home button location updates stop and approximately in 1 minute service gets killed. Again service gets killed if I kill the app from recent app tray. I have read that there are limitations for using fusedlocationproviderclient in background service. "If your app is running in the background, the location system service computes a new location for your app only a few times each hour." Is it related to this?

Service in manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".Background_Location_Service"
        android:enabled="true"></service>
```

Here I start the service:

```
Intent service_intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Background_Location_Service.class);
    service_intent.putExtra("username",username);
    startService(service_intent);
```

My service:

```
public class Background_Location_Service extends Service {
private static Double lat;
private static Double lon;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private String username;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    username = intent.getExtras().getString("username");
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lon = location.getLongitude();
                
                //Sending latitude, longitude and username to database
                Call<ResponseBody> call = Retrofit_Client
                        .getInstance()
                        .getAPI()
                        .send_location(lat, lon, username);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        try {
                            String response_status = response.body().string();
                            Toast.makeText(Background_Location_Service.this, response_status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(Background_Location_Service.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
    }
    //requesting updates
    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper());

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    super.onDestroy();
}
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 5000, pendingIntent);


}}
```

2. I learned, foreground service must be developed including notification to run a service continuously. With this approach can I achieve this? Or is there a better approach?
3. I read workmanager can be used so it will automatically deicide using jobscheduler or alarmmanager. Also it is able to cope with doze mode. So can I develop workmanager to get last known location periodically (E.g. every 5 minutes) instead of requesting location updates?

Comment: 2nd one(foreground service) is better as android 8 introduced limitation on background location , see this  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Comment: @aryanagarwal thanks for your reply. I will use foreground service as you suggested. Just asking because of curiosity. Fused location provider client gets location a few times every hour so with this approach, using foreground service can I get location updates via the interval I define instead of getting a few times? Also I have another question. Fused location provider client aims for better battery management. If I prefer the third way in which work manager will trigger periodically so considering battery usage will it perform better  than continuously working service?

Comment: Yes you can get the location but you also need to build a notification channel , yes work manager performs better than service but it is not for task like these which are recurring or at interval of few seconds